# How to "reset" CodeIgniter active record for consecutive queries?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter and have a case where two tables (projects and tasks) need to be updated with a value right after one another (active column needs to be set to "n"). The code I am using is:

```
function update($url, $id)
{
    $this->db->where('url', $url);
    $this->db->update('projects', array('active' => 'n'));
    $this->db->where('eventid', $id);
    $this->db->update('tasks', array('active' => 'n'));
}
```

With this code, the projects table gets updated but the tasks table does not. If I comment out `$this->db->update('projects', array('active' => 'n'));` then the tasks table gets updated.

I reckon this has something to do with caching but I have tried `flush_cache` before the tasks `db->update` call but that didn't have any effect.

Can someone explain how consecutive update queries can be executed using CodeIgniter?

Comment: This *should* be working correctly by default because you aren't caching the `WHERE`s, it is strange that you're having issues. Try `echo`ing `$this->db->last_query()` after each update and `exit`ing to make sure the queries are actually correct.

Answer (score 20):

Use

```
$this->db->start_cache();
```

Before starting query building and

```
$this->db->stop_cache();
```

After ending query building. Also, use

```
$this->db->flush_cache();
```

After stop cache.

Answer (score 13):

For version 3 of Codeigniter the correct way is:

`$this->db->reset_query()`

As found here: http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#resetting-query-builder

And 2022 update for version 4:

`$this->db->resetQuery();`

As found here:
https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#resetting-query-builder

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Worked perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Correct answer! Thanks

Answer (score 12):

This works:

```
$this->db->flush_cache();
```

If you don't perform a get() or similar CI does not always clear the cache. The final code looks like this:

```
$this->db->from('table');
$this->db->where('field', $field);
$count = $this->db->count_all_results();
$this->db->flush_cache();
```

Answer (score 10):

Try calling `$this->db->reset();` after the first `update` call.

EDIT: meh, try `$this->db->_reset_write();` to flush all traces of the query.

Comment: I would really recommend not using any functions that start with _* on CI. They are meant to be private functions. And they may not be available in future versions. [Sources](http://www.tig12.net/downloads/apidocs/codeigniter/database/CI_DB_active_record.class.html#det_methods__reset_write) Except for the only 2 exceptions I make which are [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/734138/best-practices-for-processing-errors-from-database-in-codeigniter)

Comment: And you are right, it is to be avoided: depending on his specific issue it may be the only way to solve it, so it is there for him. Having access to the **private by convention** methods have been quite handy from time to time, and strictly speaking they COULD have been marked as private (at least in 5.x and higher) if you were NEVER supposed to touch them. So as will all things powerful, handle with care.

Comment: Agreed, maybe add a tiny warning to you answer in case anyone uses it and is unaware of this fact? (That's sort of why I made the comment in the first place ^^)

Comment: Didn't work. I tried both variations after the first update but only the first update will get committed, the second update calls gets ignored. Again, if I comment out the first update call, the second update runs just fine. Perplexed :O

Comment: Quite odd: if you do `echo $this->db->last_query();` after the first and second calls to `update`, what gets printed out?

Answer (score 0):

In the second update call, do you need the url conditional? if so, after you call the first update that data is no longer available for the second one. You will need to set again:

```
function update($url, $id)
{
    $this->db->where('url', $url);
    $this->db->update('projects', array('active' => 'n'));
    $this->db->where('url', $url);
    $this->db->where('eventid', $id);
    $this->db->update('tasks', array('active' => 'n'));
}

// Alternatively
function update($url, $id)
{
    $where_bit = array(
        'url' => $url,
    );
    $this->db->update('projects', array('active' => 'n'), $where_bit);
    $where_bit['event_id'] = $id;
    $this->db->update('tasks', array('active' => 'n'), $where_bit);
}
```

CI active record update supports the where condition to be passed in as an array of key => value as the 3rd parameter (also as a string but id recommend using the array instead)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$this->db->reconnect();
```

after your query.

Good day!

Comment: This would reconnect the database, which would effectively reset the query but this is overkill for what the OP is trying to do.