# Delete query from proccess list with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, process

I have problem with a sleeping queries. Some tasks in my WEB tooks longer than 1min so mysql queries gets status "sleeping" until proccess will be closed. I want to close proccess just after grabbing details.

```
$delay = $this->db->select('*');
    $delay = $this->db->get('system_status');
    if($delay->num_rows() != 0) $delay = $delay->result_array();
```

and after this code should be some clear or something to delete inserted row to process list until it will be declared as "sleeping". Any ideas?

Comment: You need to renew the database connection after the 1min timeout.

Comment: how to do it with codeigniter? ant I think it would be enough just to clear this connection.

Comment: CodeIgniter has a `DB()` common function to create the database connection. you could use: `$this->db = DB();` I didn't try this myself, give it a try and let me know how it works.

Comment: `$this->db->reset();` may help

Comment: Hashem Qolami, what does exatcly this method do? I do not want to create new one connection, I want to destroy old one

Answer (score 1):

As I noted in the comments, You need to renew the database connection after the 1min timeout.

CodeIgniter has a method to reconnect the database connection:

```php
$this->db->reconnect();
```

From the [Doc](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/connecting.html):

> **Reconnecting / Keeping the Connection Alive**
>
> If the database server's idle timeout is exceeded while you're doing
>   some heavy PHP lifting (processing an image, for instance), you should
>   consider pinging the server by using the `reconnect()` method before
>   sending further queries, which can gracefully keep the connection
>   alive or re-establish it.

Comment: Thanks, but like as I said, I do not need to renew all connection, I just need to delete last query inserted into proccess list until it get status "sleeping"

Comment: @ŽydriusNežydras To reset the old queries, you might want to check this topic on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246023/how-to-reset-codeigniter-active-record-for-consecutive-queries

Comment: yes, this is something I want. But there is info how to kill all sleeping proccessess, how do I delete last one inserted?

Comment: @ŽydriusNežydras It needs to get hands dirty to hack the core files :), I'll give it a try in next 30mins.

Comment: do not push yourself if don't have time. I tried to add `$this->db->start_cache();` and `$this->db->stop_cache();` `$this->db->flush_cache();` after every query in my controller and I think it works.

Comment: @ŽydriusNežydras In `system/database/DB_active_rec.php` **[Lines #L1995-L2042](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/database/DB_active_rec.php#L1995-L2042)**, there are two reset function for `select` and `write`, which use `_reset_run()` method to reset the variables. But these methods are `protected`, you could extend the class to create your public methods, or simply change the core file.